# How to properly load DoctrineExtensions in Bisna?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I am trying to load some doctrine extensions but I get all sort of errors. So far this is what I have

In my ini:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "DoctrineExtensions"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaderClass = "Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaderFile  = "Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php"

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.DoctrineExtensions_Paginate.namespace = "DoctrineExtensions\Paginate"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.DoctrineExtensions_Paginate.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH '/../library/Doctrine/DoctrineExtensions/Paginate/'
```

And in one of my controllers:

```
  $count = Paginate::getTotalQueryResults($query); // Step 1
  $paginateQuery = Paginate::getPaginateQuery($query, $offset, $limitPerPage); // Step 2 and 3
  $result = $paginateQuery->getResult();
```

And this is the error:

> Warning: include_once(DoctrineExtensions/Paginate.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: From your question it's not visible where you actually (and how) use "Bisna"? Are you referring to the Bisna library? http://www.krueckeberg.org/notes/bisna.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something simple

```
 //include class loader first

 //make sure this is correct
 $doctrine_root=APPLICATION_PATH. '/../library/Doctrine';

 require_once $doctrine_root.'/Common/ClassLoader.php';

 $classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine',$doctrine_root);

 $classLoader->register();

 user Doctrine\DoctrineExtensions\Paginate;
```

Then try reset of the code

```
  $count = Paginate::getTotalQueryResults($query); // Step 1
  // Step 2 and 3
  $paginateQuery = Paginate::getPaginateQuery($query, $offset, $limitPerPage);  

  $result = $paginateQuery->getResult();
```

let me know how this works

cheers :)

**Note :** I haven't tested this code at my end

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try this plugin: [beberlei / DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions)

And here are the details on how to integrate it into your project: [README](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/README.markdown)

I do not think you can do so for as the developer has built the extensions! :S

In order to use the autoload for the class `Paginate`, the class should have been called `DoctrineExtensions_Paginate_Paginate`.

Good Luck!

Comment: I am using exactly beberlei.. but the way to integrate is using the classes etc.. i know exactly how to do it like that... what i am looking for is how to configure it from my application.ini...  i am using Bisna

Comment: I do not think you can do so for as the developer has built the extensions! :S
In order to use the autoload for the class "Paginate" the class should have been called "DoctrineExtensions_Paginate_Paginate"